# How would I efficiently array out certain rows?

Tags: arrays, database, sas

I am still learning how to format on stackoverflow so please bear with me.

I have my dataset currently looking like (https://i.stack.imgur.com/b89aA.jpg) However, I want to array out certain rows so that the final dataset looks like (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCPAv.jpg)

What is the most efficient way to array these values out? I have over 70 variables so writing the array statement for all of these might not be the most efficient usage of my time.

To add potential issues, the records per ID varies drastically from 1 record to 10 records.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you can achieve this by using left join on same table on ID and get the result set.

Comment: "array out" doesn't make sense. What do you really mean here?

Comment: Posting your data as a picture doesn't help with us providing a coded solution, you should really add a data step that creates the Have and Want datasets.  However, this type of question has been asked a few times before, although the answer isn't an obvious one.  Take a look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384634/sas-transpose-multiple-variables-in-rows-to-columns/25388127#25388127
or search in StackOverflow for `IDGROUP` to get similar answers

Comment: @Jimmy I dont think a left join would work as it would only stack the records.

Comment: @gregory What I mean is that the record values for each ID is right now in rows. I want to change those who have multiple records have them in columns rather than rows. I've through about PROC TRANSPOSE but I don't want to transpose everything in one column.

Comment: @Longfish Sorry, I didn't think a data set for my have and want would've been conducive to the conversation as it would be read as thru PROC IMPORT.

Comment: @Ehwic Just some dummy data along the lines of what you have would be sufficient.  Did you have a look at the link I put in?  Modifying my answer in there to suit your data should be very easy.