# Setting names to idgroup

Tags: sas

Follow up to 
[SAS - transpose multiple variables in rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384634/sas-transpose-multiple-variables-in-rows-to-columns)

I have the following code:

```
data have;
input CX_ID 1. TYPE $1. COUNT_RATE 1. SUM_RATE 2.;
datalines;
1A110
1B220
2A120
    ;
run;


    proc summary data = have nway;
        class cx_id;
        output out=want (drop = _:)
        idgroup(out[2] (count_rate sum_rate)= count sum);
    run;
```

So this table:

```
    CX_ID  TYPE COUNT_RATE SUM_RATE
    1       A       1        10
    1       B       2        20
    2       A       1        20
```

becomes

```
CX_ID  COUNT_1 COUNT_2 SUM_1 SUM_2
1       1       2       10     20
2       1       .       20      .
```

Which is perfect, but how do I set the names to be

```
Count_A Count_B Sum_A Sum_B
```

Or in general whatever the value in the type field of the have table ?

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you change the class from CX_ID to your Type instead? or both in the CLASS statement?

Comment: Your code, as posted, doesn't work.

Comment: I need the final table by Cx_ID. The idea is to have count of product codes and sum of rates by Cx_ID by Type in one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double PROC TRANSPOSE is dynamic and you can add a data step to customize the names easily.

```
*sample data;

data have;
    input CX_ID 1. TYPE $1. COUNT 1. SUM 2.;
    datalines;
1A110
1B220
2A120
    ;
run;

*transpose to long;

proc transpose data=have out=long;
    by cx_id type;
run;

*transpose to  wide;

proc transpose data=long out=wide;
    by cx_id;
    var col1;
    id _name_ type;
run;
```